# Page print preview no data on first try

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay this is weird. This is the first time I try out printing of the page and I hope I can keep it simple. The thing is it works, it actually does (why wouldn't it). BUT, the problem is when I hit the "print" button the first time since page loaded it previews almost blank page. Some content (borders) load but the main text does not.
The code was simple  but I assumed that it would be better to place the function in document ready of jQuery script. So the whole script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".prijava").click(function(){
    $("#forma").slideToggle("fast");
});
$(".stampaj").click(function(){
    window.print();
});});
```

Aaand here are the pictures too. First one shows how it looks like on the FIRST click, and second one on second click. If I refresh the page it works but if I close it and start it again it fails for the first time again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1tlQ.jpg

(I hope links are ok here)

Thank you :)

Comment: try window.load

Comment: Could it be anything to do with the `$(".stampaj")` click handler? Here's my tentative guess: When you click the print button, it also clicks a `.prijava`. (Maybe the `.prijava` is an ancestor of the `.stampaj` in the HTML tree.) Then the `slideToggle` makes changes to the page, and the content somehow (?) becomes visible to the printer. But because it's animated, and the print happens immediately, it's not there in time for the first print.

Comment: The first click function has nothing to do with print button (.stampaj). They are not even close in HTML tree. :/

Answer (score 0):

The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

```
    window.onLoad=function() {
    $(".prijava").click(function(){
        $("#forma").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $(".stampaj").click(function(){
        window.print();
    });
   }
```

Comment: $(window).load(.. is deprecated function so I used "$(window).on('load',function()...." sadly the problem remains as it was before.